# Finding the reminder of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

How do I find the reminder of $X^{10}$ divided by ${(X+1)^3}$? Is there an easy way besides actually doing the division?

Comment: Polynomial division really isn't that complicated. Synthetic division may be a neater representation, but it uses the same method.

Comment: I guess substitute $T=X+1$.

Comment: You need find the remainder of $X^{10}$ by $X^3+3X^2+3X+1$ using the Euclidean division. That is, you need to do the same steps in your division of polynomials in the same way that you know how do it with integer numbers. Since $10=\deg(X^{10})\ge \deg (X^3+3X^2+3X+1)=3$  and 
 $$\text{dividend}=\text{divisor}\cdot \text{quotient}+\text{remainder}$$
 we can do such first step (just to emphasize, using your algorithm for division of integers) and write  $$X^{10}= (X^3+3X^2+3X+1)\cdot X^7+(-3X^9-3X^8-X^7).$$

Comment: Now you need to continue the division with dividend $-3X^9-3X^8-X^7$ and (same) divisor $X^3+3X^2+3X+1$, you can do it since the degree of the dividend, $9$, is greater or equal than $3$. Good luck, I presume that there are detailed examples in internet about eucliden division of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remainder has the form $aX^2+bX+c$. Let $Q(X)$ be the quotient. Then

$$X^{10}=(X+1)^3Q(X)+aX^2+bX+c$$

$$10X^9=3(X+1)^2Q(X)+(X+1)^3Q'(X)+2aX+b$$

$$90X^8=6(X+1)Q(X)+6(X+1)^2Q'(X)+(X+1)^3Q''(X)+2a$$

Substitute $X=-1$ into each of the above $3$ equalities.

Or as suggested by G. Sassatelli, let $T=X+1$. Then $X^{10}=(T-1)^{10}$. We can obtain the remainder by expanding the binomial.

Comment: Thank you for the first solution,I tried solving it like that but I stopped at the second derivate.Is there a trick when expanding the binomial because otherwise it would be kind of difficult to calculate (T-1)^10\T^3

Comment: $(T-1)^{10}=1-\binom{10}{1}T+\binom{10}{2}T^2+\text{terms in higher powers of }T$. The remainder is $1-10T+45T^2=1-10(X+1)+45(X+1)^2$. It's not very complicated.